# can't export template visual Studio 2010 in a .zip

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Ok, so i was looking [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/VSExtnsnsTemplates2010.aspx) in `codeproject` website and in the video its shows a part when i click `File-> Export Template`. But in my Visual studio doesn't appear like that, instead appears like this `File-> Export Template as VSIX` an I cannot see the .zip generated from my template, instead generates a `.vsix` that I can modify. Do I need to install another extension??. Or i need to do something else.

Comment: Did you get the Project or Item dialog first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be VS install issue. But you can define a keyboard shortcut that points to `File.ExportTemplate` within *Tools -> Options -> Keyboard* and still try this feature.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the MSDN documentation "A VSIX package is a compressed file that follows the Open Packaging Conventions (OPC) standard" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff363239.aspx. You could probably rename the extesion to .zip and then open it open and poke around.